# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON and internal server 500

Tags: next.js, fetch, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am getting internal 500 server error and Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

when I go to http://localhost:3000/api/chatgpt I am facing Error: Request failed with status code 429

this is my generate end point

```
  const callGenerateEndpoint = async () => {
    setApiOutput(`Please Wait ....`);

    console.log("Calling OpenAI...");
    const response = await fetch("/api/chatgpt", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ userInput, checked }),
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    const { output } = data;
    console.log("OpenAI replied...", output.text);

    setApiOutputForRemix(output.text)

    const formattedText = output.text.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
    const sanitizedOutput = sanitizeHtml(formattedText);

    setApiOutput(`${sanitizedOutput}`);
```

this is my chatgpt completion

```
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from 'openai';

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

var basePromptPrefix = `Create a solidity smart contract for `;
var selectOpenZeppelin = "";
var versionUser = " use solidity version 0.8.17";
const chatGPT = async (req, res) => {

    if(req.body.checked == true) {
        selectOpenZeppelin = ` Using OpenZeppelin`;
    }

    const baseCompletion = await openai.createCompletion({
      model: 'text-davinci-003',
      prompt: `${basePromptPrefix}${req.body.userInput}${selectOpenZeppelin}${versionUser}`,
      temperature: 0.6,
      max_tokens: 4000,
    });

    const data_output = baseCompletion.data.choices.pop();

  // Send over the Prompt #2's output to our UI instead of Prompt #1's.
  res.status(200).json({ output: data_output });
};

export default chatGPT;
```

I didn't understand error. I am expecting to true response

Comment: Maybe look up what HTTP status code 429 means? :)

Comment: I know its about too many request